# In the mario problem of problem set 6 , console prints an extra space in the starting of every line

Tags: python, cs50

when i run my code , the printing starts from counter 1 instead of 0 and also the number of "#" in the last line of the pyramid is 1 less then it should be

```
from cs50 import get_int

n = 0

while n < 1 or n > 8:     
       n = get_int("height :")

for i in range(n):   
    for j in range(2*n + 2):   
        if j > n-i-1 and j < n+1 :  
            print("#",end="")  
        elif j > n+2 and j <= n+i+3 :  
            print("#",end="")  
        else :  
            print(" ",end="")  

    print()
```

```
$ python mario.py
height :8
        #  #      
       ##  ##     
      ###  ###    
     ####  ####   
    #####  #####  
   ######  ###### 
  #######  #######
 ########  #######
```

notice every line has an extra space in the starting and also 1 "#" is missing at the end of line 8

Comment: `elif j >= n+2 and j < n+i+3:`

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed, The last line is supposed to start with `#` instead of `space`. The reason it didn't, is because in the last iteration (i.e when `i=3 and j=0`), the first condition `j > n-i-1` becomes `0 > 4-3-1` which means `0 > 0`. It's false, so the code print the `space` in the else block.

To avoid this, change `for j in range(2*n + 2)` to `for j in range(1, 2*n + 3)`